# continue if loop if failed

Tags: c#, .net, loops, for-loop

I am using the following to loop through date range and import into a database from text files. I want to know how can I tell the code IF FILE DOES NOT EXITS THEN CONTINUE TO NEXT FILE?

```
for (DateTime date = last_date; date.Date <= DateTime.Today; date = date.AddDays(1))
{
  string file_name = "H" + date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + ".TXT";

  MySqlBulkLoader bl = new MySqlBulkLoader(sql_connection);
  bl.TableName = "processing_table";
  bl.FieldTerminator = ",";
  bl.LineTerminator = "\n";
  bl.FileName = @"C:\Temp\Attendence\" + file_name;
  bl.NumberOfLinesToSkip = 0;

  int count = bl.Load();

  string sql = "SELECT source, created_date, created_time, company, action, employee_number, employee_name, outlet, field_1, field_2, field_3, field_4 FROM processing_table";
  MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, sql_connection);
  MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

  while (rdr.Read())
  {
      SplashScreenManager.Default.SetWaitFormDescription(rdr[1] + " - " + rdr[2]);
  }

  rdr.Close();
}
```

Comment: umm... `if (File.Exists(...))` around the code in the loop? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (!File.Exists(@"C:\Temp\Attendence\" + file_name)) { continue; }
```

Add this line after your `string file_name =` line. Placing it here prevents unnecessary initialization of your `MySqlBulkLoader`.

`continue` Will skip the rest of the code and hit the next item in your loop. See the [c# reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/923ahwt1.aspx) for an example.